$\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{s}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1)}$ or $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{s}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1)}$?
I have
$$\log(\xi(s)) = \log(s-1)-\frac{s}{2}\log(\pi)+\log(\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1))+\log(\zeta(s))$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the Zeta Function, $\Gamma(s)$ is the Gamma Function and
$$\xi(s) = \frac{1}{2}s(s-1)\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s).$$
When I take the derivate in the first equation I should have:
$$\frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)} = \frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{2}log(\pi)+\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{s}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1)}+\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)},$$ don't I?
However, my Proffesor wrote:
$$\frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)} = \frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{2}\log(\pi)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{s}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}+1)}+\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}.$$
Could any one tell me why, please?

First of all, while writing something  like "$\log(\xi(s))$" is okay for intuition, I think it is a terrible idea to work with such things in a loose way because there is no such thing as a logarithm function on all of $\mathbf C^\times$ and the usual way it is defined by omitting the negative real axis from its domain gives $\log f(s)$ no meaning in case $f(s)$ is negative. Moreover, that logarithm function does not convert products to sums or ratios to differences.
It is stylistically much better to deal directly with the logarithmic derivative function operation $f(s) \leadsto f'(s)/f(s)$ when $f$ is a meromorphic function on some domain in $\mathbf C$.  Intuitively, the logarithmic derivative is a "composite" of log and differentiation, but passing from $f(s)$ to $f'(s)/f(s)$ makes direct sense without requiring any notion of a complex logarithm and its lack of good properties.
Check by direct calculation that the operation $f(s) \leadsto f'(s)/f(s)$ sends products to sums and ratios to differences: $fg \leadsto f'/f + g'/g$ by the product rule for derivatives and $f/g \leadsto f'/f - g'/g$. Also, $f^n \leadsto nf'/f$ for all integers $n$ (including negative integers).
Some specific examples of logarithmic derivatives are $s + c \leadsto 1/(s+c)$, $a^s \leadsto \log a$ (a constant answer) when $a$ is a positive real number (we have no issues with the ordinary real logarithm on positive real numbers!), and $f(bs + c) \leadsto b f'(bs + c)/f(bs+c)$ where $b$ and $c$ are constants. You want that with $b = 1/2$ and $c = 1$, which explains where the outside factor $1/2$ comes from that you missed, taking $f(s) = \Gamma(s)$.
Writing $\xi(s) = (s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma((1/2)s + 1)\zeta(s)$, the nice properties of logarithmic derivatives of meromorphic functions tells us that $\xi(s)$ has logarithmic derivative
$$
\frac{1}{s-1} + \log(\pi^{-1/2}) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma'(s/2 + 1)}{\Gamma(s/2 + 1)} + \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)},
$$
and $\log(\pi^{-1/2}) = -(1/2)\log \pi$.
